# MySQL Combining data from multiple tables (foreign key) into an array

Tags: mysql, sql, json, subquery

What I'm trying to accomplish is query the data for all categories in the categories table, but also add a "posts" property that lists out the IDs of all posts within that category into an array.

Database tables:

```
'categories' table
+---------+----------+
|      id | title    |
+---------+----------+
|     100 | "categ1" |
|     101 | "categ2" |
|     102 | "categ3" |
|     103 | "categ4" |
+---------+----------+

'posts' table
+---------+----------+----------+
|      id | title    | category |
+---------+----------+----------+
|       1 | "abc"    | 100      |
|       2 | "def"    | 101      |
|       3 | "ghi"    | 100      |
|       4 | "jkl"    | 102      |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

Output goal: (json_encode, manually add 'categories' to top-level)

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 100,
            "title": "categ1",
            "posts": [1, 3] (Post IDs of those in category 10)
        }
        {
            "id": 102,
            "title": "categ2",
            "posts": [2]
        }
        {
            "id": 103,
            "title": "categ3",
            "posts": [4]
        }
        {
            "id": 104,
            "title": "categ4",
            "posts": []
        }
    ]
}
```

While the basic query of getting the categories is easy, I can't figure out a way to generate the posts property based off the posts table and the posts category/category id relationship.

Can provide any more information if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it sounds like you're looking for `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
select c.id, c.title, group_concat(p.id) posts
from categories c
  left join posts p on c.id = p.category
group by c.id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da4bb0/2)

Comment: Ah yeah this was exactly what I was looking for (short of the array, but seems I'll have to manually explode it anyways so no issue there). Thanks!